# How to generate xlsx file using xlsxwriter in Django framework?

Tags: django, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am using **xlsxwriter**
Able to generate xlsx file with the help of **xlsxwriter**.

Reference Example:

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_http_server.html Example for reference.

If this example is executing then On command prompt following statement is coming

**Server listening on port 7777...**

How should I generate xlsx file using django framework on local server?
 and where I will find that xlsx file saved?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid : Yes it is similar to xlwt. But How to do the same thing with xlsxwriter ? Any help?

Comment: The same solution posted there will work for you; the problem is not with `xlswriter`.